# A non-linear map $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(av) = af(v)$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}, ~ v \in \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a non-linear map $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(av) = af(v)$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}, ~ v \in \mathbb{R}^2$? I thought taking $f(x,y) = \sqrt{y^2}$ but it doesn't cover all of $\mathbb{R}$, nor satisfies $f(av) = af(v)$ for *all* $a \in \mathbb{R}, ~ v \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try considering the magnitude of elements in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a starting point.

$$f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$

It's clearly linear with respect to multiplication for *positive* $a$, but what happens if you consider any two points that aren't mutually collinear with the origin?

The problem here is that it doesn't have the power to distinguish the sign of $a$ (and it seems you want a surjective map).

You could update it without much effort:  let instead $f(x,y) = \text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ or anything along those lines.

*Here I mean $\text{sgn(x)}$ to be the signum function which evaluates to $0$ when $x = 0$ and is otherwise $x/|x|$*

Comment: Neither of the maps you considered satisfy $f(av)=af(v)$ for _all_ $a\in\mathbb R$ and $v\in\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: what's wrong with the second one, i thought i check cases there? But certainly the first one doesn't work for negative values of $a$

Comment: What happens if $v=(0,y)$ for  the second one?

Comment: $f(0,y) = 0$ since $sign(0) = 0$, and then $f(a0, ay) = a0 = f(0,y)$ for any $a$??

Comment: You're right, I didn't know you were using that sign convention for $0$.

Comment: i will update for clarity. actually i should have written sgn instead of sign to show clearly i intended the signum function.  I was assuming it would be clear by inference (otherwise you'd have been right about it being wrong!) thanks for taking notice.

Comment: Thanks guys. @BadamBaplan was the problem with the first one that it sent everything to non-negative reals or just the sign of the constant? Also, does the new function distinguish the sign of $a$ always (e.g. when both $x$ and $a$ are negative)?

Comment: Right, the first one had its image in $[0, \infty)$, whereas I think you wanted the image to be $\mathbb{R}$ entirely (a surjective function).  

Additionally, the first one had the property that $f(ax,ay) = |a|f(x,y)$ which is not quite right.  

The second function works because the signum function is multiplicative.  You can check that $\text{sgn}(ax) = \text{sgn}(x)\text{sgn}(a)$, there are essentially $4$, pos/pos, pos/neg, neg/neg, and 0/something

Comment: @BadamBaplan Thanks. Took me a while to digest this example, but it's beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** This hint assumes you are comfortable with identifing $\mathbb R^2$ with $\mathbb C$. Consider the map $f(re^{i\theta})=r\sin\theta e^{i\theta}$. Is $f(av)=af(v)$ true? However, is $f(1+i)=f(1)+f(i)$ true?

Comment: The codomain of this function is larger than the real numbers.

Comment: Take the real part of the function.

Comment: @rnrstopstraffic Thanks for pointing out. I was reading the question as finding a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$... But fortunately it was not a big problem: as Tim Carson said, we only need to take the real part of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\{(\cos A, \sin A): A\in [0,\pi)\}.$ For each $v\in S$ choose an arbitrary $f(v)\in \Bbb R.$ And for  $a\in \Bbb R$ and $v\in S$ let $f(av)=af(v).$

For example let $f(1,0)=f(0,1)=1$ and $f(1/\sqrt 2\;,1/\sqrt 2\;)=1000000.$ Obviously $f(u)+f(v)\ne f(u+v)$ if $u=(1/\sqrt 2\;,0)$ and $v=(0,1/\sqrt 2\;).$